# Set Facebook Name in a dialog

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, android-dialog

When I'm connected by the facebook login button, I launch a custom dialog (in the **onSuccess**) and I want to write in this dialog the name of the person connected. It works when I do it in the layout called in onCreate(I make appear the name after connexion). But it doesn't work when I want to write this in the layout called by the dialog after the connexion (but it's the same activity).

Here is my code :

```
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager2;    
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker2;
    private LoginButton loginbutton2;  

    final Context context = this;
    private ProfilePictureView fAvatar2;
    private TextView fName2;    

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback2 = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            /*
                LAUNCH DIALOG ABOUT FACEBOOK CONNEXION
             */

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialogFacebookConnexion = new Dialog(context);
            dialogFacebookConnexion.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_facebook_connect);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialogFacebookConnexion.findViewById(R.id.dialogOk);

            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialogFacebookConnexion.dismiss();
                    Intent intentmainpage = new Intent(InfoAccountActivity.this, MainPageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentmainpage);
                }
            });

            dialogFacebookConnexion.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            int dialogHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_height);
            int dialogWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_width);
            dialogFacebookConnexion.getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
            dialogFacebookConnexion.show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_account);

        mCallbackManager2 = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginbutton2 = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button2);
        loginbutton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.facebookconnexion);
        loginbutton2.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginbutton2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        loginbutton2.registerCallback(mCallbackManager2, mCallback2);


        fName2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.facebookName2);
        fAvatar2 = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.facebook_avatar2);

        ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                OnProfileChanged(newProfile);
            }
        };
    }

    private void OnProfileChanged (Profile profile) {
        if (profile != null) {

            try {
                fName2.setText(profile.getName());
                fAvatar2.setProfileId(profile.getId());

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        } else {

        }

    }

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        OnProfileChanged(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager2.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Is it a problem with **private** or **protected** ? An information can't be access by the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Request.newMeRequest using your active open session? It is easy to capture the logged user's profile afterwards.

```
GraphRequest rq = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(final GraphUser user, Response response) { ...
...
rq.executeAndWait();
```

You can retrieve the user's name by user.getName() in the onCompleted method and use it anywhere.

Comment: thanks but I don't need to use this method normally. It works in the layout called by the onCreate(), but not in the layout called by the dialog (however in the same activity)

Answer (score 0):

In any activity, you can use the following facebook code from their SDK once you have signed into Facebook:

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getName()
```

Comment: . If it doesn't work, consider putting the name into a bundle object and pass it to the dialog.